# SQL : combine 2 rows into 1

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This is my database

[image: | | |]

I'm trying to display "hello" and "wo" in the same column

My SQL statement:

```sql
SELECT 
    d.CampaignId, d.ClientID, 
    citn.ImagePath AS Thumbnail, cidi.ImagePath AS DetailImage
FROM  
    MasterData.CampaignImage AS d 
INNER JOIN
    MasterData.CampaignImage AS citn ON d.CampaignId = citn.CampaignId  
                                     AND d.ClientID = citn.ClientID 
                                     AND citn.ImageTypeId = 1 
INNER JOIN
    MasterData.CampaignImage AS cidi ON d.CampaignId = cidi.CampaignId 
                                     AND d.ClientID = cidi.ClientID 
                                     AND cidi.ImageTypeId = 2
```

The output:

[image]

But now I have 2 rows in my output, how can I combine these into just one row?

Comment: Simply `SELECT DISTINCT`?

Comment: @jarlh thanks, could you post this as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name im using microsoft sql studio so I quess its mssql but im not sure

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply do `SELECT DISTINCT` to skip duplicate rows.